# React pass ajax data to children

Tags: javascript, ajax, reactjs, async-await, frontend

How I can pass to child component from parent data requested by ajax call? 
For example I have code like that

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch();

    this.setState(response.data);
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <ChildComponent data={this.state} /> // data={}
    );
  }
}
```

Problem here is ChildComponent will be mount before data will be fetch so I will get empty object data in ChildComponent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if data is available or not

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch();

    this.setState(response.data);
  }

  render() { // Return if response is Object
    return Object.keys(this.state).length > 0
      ? <ChildComponent data={this.state} /> // data={}
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  }

  render() { // Return if response is Array
    return this.state.length > 0
      ? <ChildComponent data={this.state} /> // data={}
      : <div>Loading...</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: @Axnyff He is passing full state so he knows what he is doing, we are just providing him pseudo code

Comment: Yes, I read too fast his initial code and deleted my comment, you are right

Comment: But how it can help me? I will just always get "Loading..."

Comment: @netseac State will get data it will check length of state and show data, my code will work if your response is Object i will update my code for Array also,

Comment: Yes. It's works. I just can't understand why before. React call render again all the time when state change. That's why it's working. Now I understand. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can decide to render the children only if there is some data.
For this, maybe don't replace the whole state with data but create a separate key. It will be easier if you need to add some other state after.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch();

    this.setState({ data: response.data });
  }

  render() {
    const { data } = this.state;
    return data ? <ChildComponent data={data} /> : null;
  }
}
```